# When do new updates appear on Windows Update?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

Microsoft normally releases new updates on [Patch Tuesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday). At this day the updates appear in the Microsoft update catalog but they are not directly made available on Windows Update. For example, on a Windows 7 installation of mine I do not see these updates offered today although there should be some. I also read on the web that this is normal.

On what day are updates normally made available on Windows Update?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Windows Updates are rolled in phases and therefore, not released to everyone by default on the date/time that they go "live". Depending on your region, timezone, etc. there could be some delay (couple of hours, or a day or two).